# Getting contents of Filetable file_stream in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ifilter, filetable

I've been setting up a SQL Server 2012 environment using a `Filetable` which is full text indexed.
Firing queries works well and I'm really happy testing this feature out.

After I installed the IFilters for PDF and MS Office documents even searching the inner contents works as a charm.

Now that I'm building a little search I'm curious if there is any way to get more then just the Document ID/Name from the results. I'd like to display the words near the found keywords to show/highlight it in the search results.

While I found many many examples how to set things up, I found no examples that got me the contents of a filestream. I think it should be possible somehow using the already installed IFilter-packages.

Whether SQL Server or something else - any approach that's efficient would be nice.

Hope anyone got an idea for me

Thanks in advance!